# Use limit with where clause in in mysql

Tags: mysql

I know where clause search and display the records as per criteria comes true, and limit is use to fetch the number of records from a table.

But please help me when I am trying to use them both together.

I have a table with following records

**Table: records**

```
+---------+--------+------------+
|  id     |  type  |   Credits  |
+---------+--------+------------+
|    1    | my     |   100      |
|    2    | my     |   200      |
|    3    | other  |   50       |
|    4    | my     |   500      |
+---------+--------+------------+
```

there are many different such records in the table after on an other.

I want to fetch any 3 records by `type` columns then I designed a following query!

```
select * from `records` 
where `type` = 'my'
limit 3
```

I got 2 results with type 'my' however I want to skip the other type data and then top 3 records with type 'my'

> How can I do this with mysql database.

thanks in anticipation!

Comment: You would get 3 rows with this query, not 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `order by credits desc` (descending) in order to get the 3 highest credits so the sql would be:

```
select * from `records` 
where `type` = 'my'
order by credits desc
limit 3;
```